# "Я в состоянии" vs "я способен"?

Tags: узус

I've come across я **в** состоянии плавать, I can (am able) to swim, and я способен, I can (am able)...

How are both of these used?

Answer (score 5):

***The short answer***

I'd say that **`я способен`** can mean both general physical ability and momentary one, **`я в состоянии`** on the other hand refers mainly to momentary ability, to translate the sentence literally `I'm being in a state/position fit for swimming`.

That said the distinction is very slim to be decisive in the choice of expression with respect to *momentary ability*.

---

***The long answer***

It's worth pointing out that for the phrase **`я способен`** :

**A)** 
1. The sense of *momentary ability* would usually be conveyed by *perfective verbs* (except for *verbs of motion* - see paragraph **B)**), i.e.

> Я способен `у`видеть
>
> Я способен `по`жертвовать

2. And  a sense of *general ability* - with *imperfective verbs*

> Я способен видеть
>
> Я способен жертвовать

**B)** 1. With the *verbs of motion* the meaning of *momentary ability* is conveyed by their *unidirectional variant* in both *perfective* and *imperfective aspects*

> Я способен плыть <sup>Uni imperf.</sup>
>
> Я способен `по/от/пере/за/под`плыть <sup>Uni perf.</sup>

*Perfective aspect* of *multidirectional verbs* conveys this meaning as well, i.e.

> Я способен `по`плавать <sup>Multi perf.</sup>
>
> Я способен `с`бегать <sup>Multi perf.</sup>

but it sounds somewhat odd and is almost never used

2. The meaning of *general ability* with *motion verbs* is indicated by their *multidirectional variant* in *imperfective aspect*

> Я способен плавать <sup>Multi imperf.</sup>
>
> Я способен бегать <sup>Multi imperf.</sup>

Comment: In an expression of general ability I'd rather use `я умею плавать`, sort of "capable of swimming".

Answer (score 4):

Semantically, ***быть в состоянии*** refers to an evident state and/or an action.

***быть способен / способным*** refers to non-evident condition and/or action.

Grammatically, ***быть в состоянии*** always-- well, *nearly always* requires an infinitive:

***Я в состоянии съесть ещё полтазика оливье, выпить ещё пол-литра, потанцевать ещё полчаса и ещё раз проголосовать на выборах. Я в состоянии отвечать за себя. Я в состоянии ехать.***

***быть способным*** ***(способен)*** + ***на*** + *A Noun in Accusative* exists in two variations (with the adjective either in Instrumental or Nominative, for details, see Instrumental Compliment), never to be used with an infinitive;

***Я способен на ответственные поступки. Я способен на пьянки и танцы.***

***быть способным (*способен)*** + a noun is in many situations interchangeable with ***оказаться способным/способен*** and conveys a modality of a new topic (a sort of revelation).

The interchangeability is not, however, complete, as ***быть способным (*способен)*** is never used with definite or single-time actuions, or actions of a higher register. Cf:

- ***Я способен на ответственность***. * ***Я способен на поездку***.

VS

***Я оказался способен / способным на ответственность.***
***Я оказался способен / способным на поездку.***

The indefinite/non-evidential actions (NB: the indefiniteness is expressed by plural) go with this structure perfectly well, e. g.

***Я способен на разговоры. Я способен на поездки***

Both types of the structure are intercheangeable with ***мочь*** + infinitive.

Comment: This is a usuful addition, yet it is outside of the scope of my response, because  my answer covers the can/to be able to - modalities and ***в состоянии опьянения/пробуждения/бодрствования/засыпания/сна/насыщения/восхищения/интоксикации/экзальтации/депрессии и т. д.*** goes with a genitive complement. The ***быть способным*** phrase in your example is more like 'to have some abilities' rather than 'to be able to do smth'.

Answer (score 0):

Literaly first mean "In condition"
I in condition [([to do])]
Я в состоянии (be able to) сделать это сам
Он в состоянии (in conditon)  алкогольного опьянения
Находясь в состоянии алкогольного опьянения (будучи пьяным when he drunked)
человек не способен (not able to) управлять транспортом. (He is not in condition for do it but he can (he's able to))

Я русский поэтому мне тяжело это объяснять на английском. Надеюсь понятно написал.